# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath was called but not showing EDIT and DELETE

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have tableView in the `UIViewController` class. I have to implement swipeable when to swipe it should show EDIT DELETE, that two action. My problem is, it's going inside the method when I swipe, but it did not show those two actions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        print("EDIT");
    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (rowAction:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
        print("DELETE");
        //  self.confirmDelete();
    }

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return [editAction,deleteAction]
}
```

I haven't implemented `tableview` controller. This `tableview` is part of my screen. Not full screen. I tried in the UITableViewController class, which was working

Any help please

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your tableview to be your viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes.TableView's row is rendered properly. When I swipe to row, it goes `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` to that method, but not showing EDIT/DELETE action

Comment: @Piraba I am also facing same problem how did you solved it can you help me .

Answer (score 3):

Add this delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this method. even though not showing